# MBProgressHUD won't display the label

Tags: ios, components, refresh, mbprogresshud

I'm using MBProgressBar in my app to display feedback whenever there is a call to a certain webService.

To do so, in the method "requestStarted" of ASIHTTPRequest, I call:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startLoader) toTarget:self];
```

Where `startLoader` is the method that pops the HUD.

Now, the thing is that whenever I call `startLoader` directly, the HUD gets displayed with no problem, but when I call the method using the `detachNewThreadSelector` thing (which is needed), the HUD is displayed but with no text label.

If I had to guess, I would say I need to force-refresh the component, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Anything having to do with the HUD will need to be done on the main/UI thread. If you are detach and put on a background thread, the HUD will likely never get those updates because your request will finish before getting back around to the main thread.